# The good and secure way to couple Prestashop 1.7 and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am building a Prestashop 1.7 e-commerce that I want too couple with wordpress for sharing header and footer at first. Both are on the same server and share the same database.
I read some articles on that but most are about PS version 1.6 and previous and consist to put this in your wordpress index.php ( for header ) :

```
// wp-content/themes/mytheme/index.php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../config/config.inc.php');
global $controllerPrestashop;
$controllerPrestashop = new FrontController();
$controllerPrestashop->init();
$controllerPrestashop->setMedia();
$controllerPrestashop->initHeader();
```

That way doesn't seems to work anymore and I got an error :

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at...
```

I tried with a PS CustomFrontController that call a template without header information but I didn't succeed to make it work as the following change in 1.7 :

```
$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'path/to/custom_content.tpl');
```

to :

```
$this->setTemplate('module:modulename/views/templates/front/custom_content.tpl')
```

Does that mean that I must create a module for this ?

I also think that it's maybe not the proper way to do that. So my question, what would be **the good and secure way to couple PS 1.7 and WP** ?

- a PS CustomFrontController called into WP index.php ? ( but how ? )
- a PS Module ?
- a PS controller that call the WP tables ?
- a WP controller that call the PS tables ? ( that work but how to share templates as one is in php and the other in Twig ? )

Thanks for your help !

Comment: My advise would be to avoid such hybrid experiment. Each of this Framework have its own weaknesses and by combining those you open new breaches for hackers to get in your system. I've seen many wordpress blog installed on the same host as a Prestashop or Magento E-commerce websites. Each time those sites were hacked, the intruder came from the blog.

Comment: Thanks, so what would be the "ideal" solution for these kind of website ( e-commerce + rich and editorial content ). I must keep the Prestashop, but the CMS part could be something else than WP. Craft CMS is very good, and more secure I guess, but I will be forced to share database or at least make queries from one CMS to the other. Is that really insecure ?